# Opposite of @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true) if I have mandatory fields?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have for example 5 fields that my User can fill later (name, nickname, e-mail, birthday, education) and I want that name,e-mail and birthday are mandatory so there has to be written something, I've found the other way around how I can ignore some fields through the `@JsonIgnoreProperties` annotation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to using excellent Bean Validation API, mentioned by an earlier answer, Jackson 2.7 adds limited support for ensuring required properties, as long as they are passed using `@JsonCreator` annotated constructor:

```
public class POJO {
  @JsonCreator
  public POJO(@JsonProperty(value="name", required=true) String name,
       @JsonProperty(value="age", required=true) int age) {
    ...
  }
```

in which case missing value for either `name` or `age` will trigger a `JsonMappingException`.

In future similar validation may be added for all kinds of properties, but for now (up to and including Jackson 2.8) only creator-based properties are validated this way.

Answer (score 2):

I'll assume you are using Jackson because you are using `@JsonIgnoreProperties`.

Jackson was designed to have validation be separate from deserializing JSON. So, you will need to use [Bean Validation](http://beanvalidation.org/1.1/spec/) in order to perform validation whether a particular field is null.

You will want to use the `@NotNull` annotation, specifically, on the fields that you want to make mandatory.